# Use js or jQuery to make icon linked to fieldset once it is activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a bootstrap template I found online to create a simple multi-step form. The template has some icons across the top that identify where the user is in the form completion process. Once they complete the form step and select the next button, the icon map at the top advances to the next step and the previous step is now activated (color changed).

I want to be able to make these icons an active link once the user has completed the step so they can quickly navigate back to a previous step (fieldset) by clicking on the icon. If they have not yet completed the step, then the icon link should not be active. How can I make the icons an active link to their associated steps once they have been activated? Below is my html and js and here is my jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/93r5y1g3/5/.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <!-- Top content -->
  <div class="top-content">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 form-box">
          <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="f1">

            <h3>Register To Our App</h3>
            <p>Fill in the form to get instant access</p>
            <div class="f1-steps">
              <div class="f1-progress">
                <div class="f1-progress-line" data-now-value="16.66" data-number-of-steps="3" style="width: 16.66%;"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="f1-step active">
                <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                <p>about</p>
              </div>
              <div class="f1-step">
                <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></div>
                <p>account</p>
              </div>
              <div class="f1-step">
                <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></div>
                <p>social</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <fieldset id="aboutInfo">
              <h4>Tell us who you are:</h4>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-first-name">First name</label>
                <input type="text" name="f1-first-name" placeholder="First name..." class="f1-first-name form-control" id="f1-first-name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-last-name">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" name="f1-last-name" placeholder="Last name..." class="f1-last-name form-control" id="f1-last-name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-about-yourself">About yourself</label>
                <textarea name="f1-about-yourself" placeholder="About yourself..." class="f1-about-yourself form-control" id="f1-about-yourself"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="f1-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
              </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="accountInfo">
              <h4>Set up your account:</h4>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="f1-email" placeholder="Email..." class="f1-email form-control" id="f1-email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="f1-password" placeholder="Password..." class="f1-password form-control" id="f1-password">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-repeat-password">Repeat password</label>
                <input type="password" name="f1-repeat-password" placeholder="Repeat password..." class="f1-repeat-password form-control" id="f1-repeat-password">
              </div>
              <div class="f1-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
              </div>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="socialInfo">
              <h4>Social media profiles:</h4>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-facebook">Facebook</label>
                <input type="text" name="f1-facebook" placeholder="Facebook..." class="f1-facebook form-control" id="f1-facebook">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-twitter">Twitter</label>
                <input type="text" name="f1-twitter" placeholder="Twitter..." class="f1-twitter form-control" id="f1-twitter">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="f1-google-plus">Google plus</label>
                <input type="text" name="f1-google-plus" placeholder="Google plus..." class="f1-google-plus form-control" id="f1-google-plus">
              </div>
              <div class="f1-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </fieldset>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
function scroll_to_class(element_class, removed_height) {
  var scroll_to = $(element_class).offset().top - removed_height;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() != scroll_to) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: scroll_to
    }, 0);
  }
}

function bar_progress(progress_line_object, direction) {
  var number_of_steps = progress_line_object.data('number-of-steps');
  var now_value = progress_line_object.data('now-value');
  var new_value = 0;
  if (direction == 'right') {
    new_value = now_value + (100 / number_of_steps);
  } else if (direction == 'left') {
    new_value = now_value - (100 / number_of_steps);
  }
  progress_line_object.attr('style', 'width: ' + new_value + '%;').data('now-value', new_value);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  /*
      Form
  */
  $('.f1 fieldset:first').fadeIn('slow');

  $('.f1 input[type="text"], .f1 input[type="password"], .f1 textarea').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('input-error');
  });

  // next step
  $('.f1 .btn-next').on('click', function() {
    var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
    var next_step = true;
    // navigation steps / progress steps
    var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-step.active');
    var progress_line = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-progress-line');

    // fields validation
    parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).addClass('input-error');
        next_step = false;
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
      }
    });
    // fields validation

    if (next_step) {
      parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function() {
        // change icons
        current_active_step.removeClass('active').addClass('activated').next().addClass('active');
        // progress bar
        bar_progress(progress_line, 'right');
        // show next step
        $(this).next().fadeIn();
        // scroll window to beginning of the form
        scroll_to_class($('.f1'), 20);
      });
    }

  });

  // previous step
  $('.f1 .btn-previous').on('click', function() {
    // navigation steps / progress steps
    var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-step.active');
    var progress_line = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-progress-line');

    $(this).parents('fieldset').fadeOut(400, function() {
      // change icons
      current_active_step.removeClass('active').prev().removeClass('activated').addClass('active');
      // progress bar
      bar_progress(progress_line, 'left');
      // show previous step
      $(this).prev().fadeIn();
      // scroll window to beginning of the form
      scroll_to_class($('.f1'), 20);
    });
  });

  // submit
  $('.f1').on('submit', function(e) {

    // fields validation
    $(this).find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('input-error');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
      }
    });
    // fields validation

  });


});
```

Comment: use .click() function, onClick="" or $("body").on("click",...

Answer (score 0):

Previous steps are marked with the class `.activated`.
So you may add an event handler which triggers the previous button like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.f1-step.activated .f1-step-icon', function() {
    $('.f1-buttons .btn.btn-previous').trigger("click");
});
```